# Android device does not display Google contacts in correct sort order

Tags: google-contacts

I cannot get Google Contacts to display my contacts in alphabetical order sorted by surname, with surname shown first.

The problem has existed since about a fortnight after I bought the phone almost a year ago although the operating system and the Contacts app have obviously been updated since then.

I'm currently running Android 11.1 (Oppo ColorOS 11.1) with (Google) Contacts 3.41.1.361694705 . The settings show

- Display -> Sort by -> Surname
- Name format -> Surname first
- Edit contacts -> Default account for new contacts -> Device

... but despite the settings, Contacts shows surname first (as wanted) but always sorts in first-name order! This is true whether I access Contacts directly, or though the Phone interface.

Curiously, if, from within Signal Messenger, I go to attach a contact card to a Signal message, then Contacts displays the contacts correctly (i.e., in alphabetical order by surname, with surname shown first). And just to be clear, this is ***not*** the Signal Messenger contact list I'm talking about here; this is the complete Google Contacts list.

What is the likely cause of the problem?
Is this a well-known bug?
Where is the sorting done? On the device, as one would hope, or by having Google do it?

Comment: There's no global setting for contact sorting. The sorting is done per app (Contacts and Phone are different apps and may have different sorting logic).

Comment: Have you analyzed [m]any individual contacts to make sure the fields are parsed into the correct fields? Every once in a while I get this too, and find that some "massaging" of the names has occurred that invalidates their previous input fields. Google is never complacent with this. Manual corrections brings them back to how I like them.